# Inferring knowledge in OWL by counting properties

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have an ontology with Person and City classes.  People travel to cities and this travel is represented in the traveledTo object property.  I'd like to add a WorldTraveler class.  People are world travelers if they have traveled to 2 or more cities.  How can I do this in my ontology?

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-64#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-64> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/chris/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-64> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

:traveledTo rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:domain :Person ;
            rdfs:range :City .

:City rdf:type owl:Class .

:Person rdf:type owl:Class .

:Bob rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
              :Person ;
     :traveledTo :London ,
                 :Ottawa ,
                 :Paris .

:Brussels rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                   :City .

:London rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 :City .

:Ottawa rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 :City .

:Paris rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                :City .

:Ralph rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                :Person ;
       :traveledTo :Rome .

:Rome rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
               :City .

:Washington rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                     :City .
```

I tried adding the following Class but it didn't seem to work:

```
:WorldTraveler rdf:type owl:Class ;
               owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Person
                                                          [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                            owl:onProperty :traveledTo ;
                                                            owl:minQualifiedCardinality "2"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
                                                            owl:onClass :City
                                                          ]
                                                        ) ;
                                     rdf:type owl:Class
                                   ] .
```

I believe that my reasoner may not be able to infer that Ralph is not a WorldTraveler because of the open world assumption.  However, it should be able to infer that Bob is a WorldTraveler because he has traveled to 3 cities.

Thanks for your help.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the open world assumption (OWA), there exists the unique name assumption (UNA). OWL does make the former (OWA) and does **not** make the latter (UNA).

You should explicitely make individuals different.

In the Turtle syntax, it should look like this:

```
:London owl:differentFrom :Paris .
```

or

```
[ rdf:type owl:AllDifferent ;
  owl:distinctMembers ( :Brussels :London :Ottawa :Paris :Rome :Washington )
] .
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was unaware of the UNA.  That solved it for me.