# OWL/Protégé : EquivalentTo Class Definition

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, pellet

It seems to me that the definition of a `EquivalentTo` class doesn't work properly in Protégé 5.2.0. Hopefully, it is a misunderstanding on my side.

Here is the example : [Link to a simple ontology that gives an unexpected result.](http://www.geo.ulg.ac.be/nys/test.owl)

The problem happens when I use a `min` cardinality condition on some `ObjectProperties`. In the provided example, the classification in `SubClassObject` of the `Object`(using Pellet) doesn't work for the `hasPart min 2 Part` but does for `hasPart min 1 Part`. As you see, the `element5` has 4 `Parts` as defined.

Has anybody ever met a similar issue?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: In Protégé, *Edit > Make all individuals different*. Possible duplicate of [Inferring knowledge in OWL by counting properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656880/inferring-knowledge-in-owl-by-counting-properties)

Comment: `min 2` needs explicit distinct individuals...OWL has **no** *Unique Names Assumption*

Comment: Thanks to the both of you ! It obviously works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@StanislavKralin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin) said : *Edit > Make all individuals different.*

In my personal experience afterwards, be aware that it will considerably increase computing time of reasoning.